Aligning plots horizontally, TikZ
I am trying to align two plots horizontally, plotted using Tikz and Pfgplots. They just become vertically aligned like in the photo, no matter how I adjust the scales and this: {0.25\textwidth}.
    \documentclass{article}
        
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    
    
 \begin{document}   
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
    
        % Start the first graph on the left
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth} 
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                scale = 0.7,
                grid = {both},
                xlabel = {Global displacement}, ylabel = {Global load},
                xmin=0, xmax=0.7, % Standardized axis limits
                ymin=0, ymax=3.0, % Standardized axis limits
                legend style={at={(0.99,0.01)},anchor=south east, draw=black,fill=white}  % Corrected legend position
            ]
            \addplot[color={rgb:red,016;green,101;blue,171}] table{./data/3000_5 1.1.txt};
            \addlegendentry{3000/5};
    
            \addplot[color={rgb:red,142;green,196;blue,222}] table{./data/3000_10 1.1.txt};
            \addlegendentry{3000/10};
    
            \addplot[color={rgb:red,179;green,021;blue,041}] table{./data/5000_5 1.1.txt};
            \addlegendentry{5000/5};
    
            \addplot[color={rgb:red,254;green,219;blue,199}] table{./data/5000_10 1.1.txt};
            \addlegendentry{5000/10};
    
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Point 1.1}
        \end{minipage}%
        \hspace{0.001\textwidth} % Space between the two graphs
    
        % Start the second graph on the right
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                scale = 0.7,
                grid={both},
                xlabel = {Global displacement}, ylabel = {Global load},
                xmin=0, xmax=0.7, % Standardized axis limits
                ymin=0, ymax=3.0, % Standardized axis limits
                legend style={at={(0.99,0.01)},anchor=south east, draw=black,fill=white}  % Same style for the second plot
            ]
            \addplot[color={rgb:red,016;green,101;blue,171}] table{./data/3000_5 1.2.txt};
            \addlegendentry{3000/5};
    
            \addplot[color={rgb:red,142;green,196;blue,222}] table{./data/3000_10 1.2.txt};
            \addlegendentry{3000/10};
    
            \addplot[color={rgb:red,179;green,021;blue,041}] table{./data/5000_5 1.2.txt};
            \addlegendentry{5000/5};
    
            \addplot[color={rgb:red,254;green,219;blue,199}] table{./data/5000_10 1.1.txt};
            \addlegendentry{5000/10};
    
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Point 1.2}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}




Welcome to TeX.SE!

Remove the empty line between the minipages. It forces a line breaks.

If you want other people to look into your problems, it would be helpful if they would actually be able to compile the code you show in your question. We don't have your external data files, so we can't compile your code.
